# gem numbers_and_words not working for decimal values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used gem numbers_and_words but it is not working for decimal values. Then I tried another gem currency-in-words but it is also not working.What gem shall I use for converting the amount in words?
Or is there any method for this ?
number_to_human is also of no use to me.
Please suggest me so that I get these outputs:
43545.347  Forty three thousand five hundred forty five and three hundred forty seven paise

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't take enough time to check out the https://github.com/bcarrere/currency-in-words gem, since in the description it gives quite a clear view on how to use the gem.

Also make sure you bundle install and restart your server.

EDIT: also make sure that you are using the American notation for digit separation with the dot (.) and not the comma (,)